# Change image src everytime someone clicks on image

Tags: jquery

So I have an image on my website. Whenever I click on it I want it to change to another image. I've got that working right now. But when I click on the changed image I want it to change back to the first image.

This is the code I have now:

```
$("#images2").attr("src", "http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#images2').on('click', function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if(src = 'http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg')
            $(this).attr('src', 'orginalimage.jpg');
        else
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg');
    });
});
```

This attaches a event on click on the image. It checks for its `src` and update it according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1bhf1e1o/

```
$('#rotate_images').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == 'http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg') src = 'img2_on.png';
        if (origsrc == 'img2_on.png') src = 'http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg';
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

src change method has a loading time for images after clicking which might result in unwanted behavior. Here is an elegant solution to your problem.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrbs8k7t/)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#image_cont img").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings("img").show();
        });
    
    });
```

```css
 .hidden{
        display:none;
    }
    img{
        width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_cont">
        <img src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg"/>
        <img class="hidden" src="http://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/google-panda-penguin.jpg"/>
    </div>
```